# What is the difference between error function and loss function in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

I was reading about difference between error function and loss function in other questions but I didn't got the clarity what's the exact distance. In laymen term what I understood is error function is used to calculate the distance between predicted and actual output, and loss function is mean of that error function.

Kindly correct if I am wrong. An mathematical answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: this question is answered on stats exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359068/163218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an example of root mean squared error which is an error function used to find the difference between actual value and predicted value.

mean squared loss function is used to find the least error in the mean squared error in the given heuristic state space (list of possible models).